# JavaScript Removing text between < and >

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Here is my example string...

```
<span>&nbsp;</span><span class="citation_text" id="_148511159">Rawls, Wilson.&nbsp;
<i>Where the Red Fern Grows: The Story of Two Dogs and a Boy</i>. Garden City, NY: Doubleday, 1961. Print.</span>
```

I want to remove all text within the `<` and `>` however keep the ones for `<i>` and `</i>`.
The closest I have gotten is with this piece of code

```
string.replace(/<.[^i]+?>/g,"")
```

however it return this

```
&nbsp;<span class="citation_text" id="_148511159">Rawls, Wilson.&nbsp;
<i>Where the Red Fern Grows: The Story of Two Dogs and a Boy</i>. Garden City, NY: Doubleday, 1961. Print.
```

How do I get it to remove the final span that is held in the `<` and `>`?

Thanks!

UPDATE:  This is what I would like the output to be.

```
&nbsp;Rawls, Wilson.&nbsp; <i>Where the Red Fern Grows: 
The Story of Two Dogs and a Boy</i>. Garden City, NY: Doubleday, 1961. Print.
```

Comment: Could you show the exact expected output that should be produced from your posted example string?

Comment: Instead of aiming for a complicated regex, you could write a couple of lines of jQuery to `unwrap()` the `contents()` of your spans. Just saying.

Comment: [You. Can't. Parse. HTML. With. Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @DavidThomas : Thanks, I just added that to the post!  
Oriol : I am getting the innerHTML contents first as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** As others said, you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML.
> But if you really want a regex, here is one that removes tags except `<i>` ones.

#### Regex

```
/<\/?(?!i>)\w+.*?>/g
```

This expression will match both opening and closing tags.

You can look at the example below or at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/e8bv2a/1).

### Example

```js
var str = '<span>&nbsp;</span><span class="citation_text" id="_148511159">Rawls, Wilson.&nbsp; <i>Where the Red Fern Grows: The Story of Two Dogs and a Boy</i>. Garden City, NY: Doubleday, 1961. Print.</span>';

var result = str.replace(/<\/?(?!i>)\w+.*?>/g, '');

console.log(result);
```

### Explanation

- `<\/?` matches tag opening and possible slash (for closing tags).
- `(?!i>)` prevents the match if following characters are `i>`.
  It will exclude `<i>` and `</i>` tags.
- `\w+` represents the tag name (for example `span`).
- `.*?>` is for any characters that follows the tag name (or nothing) before  closing the tag.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for!